# Measure Tool Error on GIS Flex Application

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api

On my organization's Flex Application, we use a Measure Tool that is provided by the Geometry Service from this website: https://tasks.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer.

After drawing a polygon for square footage or acreage measurement, and/or a line distance measurement, this error will pop up:

[FaultEvent fault=[RPC Fault faultString="HTTP request error" faultCode="Server.Error.Request" faultDetail="Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032"]. URL: http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/lengths?polylines=%5B%7B%22paths%22%3A%5B%5B%5B1586837%2E9747440305%2C310141%2E3985628667%5D%2C%5B1617457%2E4437312013%2C287527%2E401429212%5D%5D%5D%7D%5D&f=json&sr=102685"] messageId="9BFCC0A8-2A2C-0213-D8AD-02E8928637F5" type="fault" bubbles=false cancelable=true eventPhase=2]

Any thoughts on why this error occurs?  Could the Geometry Service be getting too many requests?

Comment: That server is an old server using ArcGIS 10.0 service pack 4.  Do you get the same error when using a newer GeometryServer?